# How to implement Binary Search into this program in Python instead of using input

Tags: python, binary-search

(title)
This program select a random number and the user have to input the number in terminal to guess it. I want to instead of using normal inputs in the terminal, I want an algorithm to find the number

```
from random import ranNum
n = ranNum(1000)
while True:
    g = int(input())
    if n == g:
        print('You won!')
        break
    print('Smaller' if (n < v ) else 'Bigger')
```

Comment: is `ranNum` an alias?

Comment: ranNum is not an alias

Comment: I don't see ranNum here: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html

Comment: I'm not sure. I got the code from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBezqslQslc I just want to see an algorithm solve it

Comment: I guess that should be `randrange` instead

Comment: @lmquan I added an answer. Could you check if it satisfies your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a binary search algorithm which guesses the number by getting the half of the remaining options for every step e.g. to get `700` then the steps would be find it in the middle of `0-1000`, then `500-1000`, then `500-750`, then `625-750`, and so on until we reach `700`.

```
from random import randrange

n = randrange(1000)
print("Number to guess:", n)

low, mid, hig = 0, 500, 1000

while True:
    if mid == n:
        print('You won!', mid)
        break
    elif mid < n:
        print('Bigger than', mid)
        low = mid
        mid = (mid + hig) // 2
    elif mid > n:
        print('Smaller than', mid)
        hig = mid
        mid = (mid + low) // 2
```

**Output**

```
Number to guess: 862
Bigger than 500
Bigger than 750
Smaller than 875
Bigger than 812
Bigger than 843
Bigger than 859
Smaller than 867
Smaller than 863
Bigger than 861
You won! 862
```

It took 10 steps, thus proving the logarithmic complexity `O(log n)` of binary searches since `log 1000 = ~10`.